# How to debug android application using android sdk?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development, I am finding it difficult to debug my program I am always getting some abstract message like "your application stopped working" I need to know exactly. I have read there are many ways to debug. What I need to know is the way which will be easy for beginners like me.

Comment: Are you using the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse (if not you should, is the easiest way to develop/debug for android) take a look at these tutorials, specially the second one (there is a lot more out there if you google a little):

- http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/11/21/starting-a-debug-session-for-android-with-adt

the main point you should research about is LogCat and debugger (both covered in the above links)

Comment: 2nd link is not working now. I see this link is refrenced many times in Stackoverflow. Google is even not having cached version. Any option?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse always look at the logCat output in the DDMS or Debug window when the app crashes. Often (buried in the output) is a line telling you exactly what statement (file and line number) caused the crash. Sometimes you need to hit resume (F8) in the Debug window to get the output. Once you get that info you could set a breakpoint at the offending statement and then look at what variable(s) are messed up.